# How to extract text from commented HTML tag

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I have a page I've parsed with Nokogiri but I need to get the text from a commented tag. The HTML is below:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <span class="visible"> hello </span>
    <!-- <span class="commented"> hi </span> -->
  </div>
</div>
```

assuming I have the page as a Nokogiri `page` object this is what I've tried but it gives me `0`:

```
page.xpath("//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='child']/comment()").each {|comment| comment.text }
```

Running only:

```
page.xpath("//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='child']/comment()")
```

gives:

```
[#<Nokogiri::XML::Comment:0x3fe466d8d634 " <span class=\"commented\">hi  </span> ">]
```

I'm out of ideas on trying how to fetch the `hi` text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not a Nokogiri expert but something like this seems to work

```
comment_node = Nokogiri::HTML(page.at("//div[@class='parent']/div[@class='child']/comment()").text)
comment_node.text.strip
 => "hi"
```

Comment: Yes it does. Love this xD